# $\text{Gal}(L|\Bbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> I am trying to show that $$\text{Gal}(L|\Bbb{Q}) \cong \Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$$ where $L = \Bbb{Q}\Big(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\Big)$.

So first, I   showed minimal polynomial of $a=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ is $x^4-4x^2+2$ with splitting field $\Bbb{Q}(a)$. This splitting field has degree $4$ which implies that $|\text{Gal}(L/\Bbb{Q})| = 4$? I am not sure if this is correct and what follows from here.

Comment: What other roots of your minimal polynomial sre there, and how do the automorphisms of $L/Q$ act on them?

Comment: Is the cyclic group of order 4 the same as $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$?